# Get digits within brackets using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some text in different formats within my DOM body like this

```
(min-width: 400px)
(max-width : 500px)
(min-width :600px)
( max-width:700px )
```

I want to detect only digits from these formats & return them in to array

I tried

```
document.write($('body').text().match(/ *\([^)\d+]*\) */g, ""));
```

But it returns null. What I'm doing wrong ?

Here is fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gQHT2/1/

Comment: What is the exact format you want to parse? Is the `:` always present?

Comment: how do you define format there ? ###px ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is using the following regexp:

```
/\(\D*(\d+)px\s*\)/g
```

This will match a `(`, any non-number garbage, the number itself with `px` appended, any spaces and a trailing `)`. The number is grouped (enclosed with `()`), so that you can get the result separately if you use `regexp.exec`: http://jsfiddle.net/gQHT2/9/.

```
$("body").html(function(i, html) {
    var regexp = /\(\D*(\d+)px\s*\)/g;
    var items = "";
    var current;
    while(current = regexp.exec(html)) {
        items += current[1] + "<br>";  // [0] is match, [1] is first group
    }
    return items;
});
```

Comment: Minor cleanup: you can change `[^\d]` into `\D`.

Comment: @pimvdb How can I get this in to array ?

Comment: @MANnDAaR: What array? Instead of `items +=` you might want `items.push(current[1])` and use `items = []` instead.